# Как описать сложность расчета глубины графика DFS?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы, сложность, dfs

Как описать сложность расчета глубины графика DFS?
Можно реализация сложность алгоритма?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут все просто - для каждого ребра выполняется некоторая (конкретная) работа O(1), так что имеем O(n), где n - количество ребер графа...